# Photo uploader send response to client

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, formidable

My code allows a client to upload multiple photos and places them in a folder. After uploading the photo, right now it just refreshes the upload page. I want to get it to go to a different page with a "Photos uploaded" response of some sort.

I think res.write or res.send would be a good solution, but I can't figure out where to put it. I have an HTML page for the uploader page, but know that res.send should output a new page with the text on it.

```
var express = require('express');
var formidable = require('formidable');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/', function (req, res){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req);

    form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file){
        file.path = __dirname + '/uploads/' + file.name;
    });

    form.on('file', function (name, file){
        console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);
    });

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000);
```